# How does one pick control points to control Bézier curves in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[Note: the system didn't like the word 'you' in my question. It prefers 'one'. Go figure.]

When I first used TikZ, I struggled to draw curves using control points.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw (0,0) .. controls (1,1) and (2,-1) .. (3,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This works great if I happen to want a curve like this

[image: curve]

But if I want a curve like this

[image: curve]

I have no idea how to figure out how to substitute for the question marks

```
  \draw (0,0) .. controls (??,??) and (??,??) .. (3,0);
```

*Note that I know the two images look identical. That is because they are the same image. That's my point.*

When I discovered TikZ offered *other* ways to draw curves, I essentially gave up on Bézier curves altogether.

But in many cases, Bézier curves look nicer and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) assures me that they can be controlled 'intuitively' by control points which is why they are so popular in drawing computer graphics.

I understand that what Wikipedia probably has in mind is a GUI, where the curves can be controlled more-or-less intuitively by adjusting control points. (I take it this is what I do in GIMP, for example.)

But how can I figure out which control points to specify in order to draw a particular curve without doing it by mere trial-and-error?

Indeed, how can I decide when to draw a curve using this method rather than one of the other curve-drawing methods TikZ provides?

I'm not asking how to calculate precise values. I want to know how to get an intuitive idea of roughly what might be about right. I want to have a sense of when doing it this way rather than some other way might make sense.

Comment: I've always consider the control point as points that "pull the path towards them". See this examples: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}`

Comment: `\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (8,3);
\draw 
  (1,0) 
    .. controls (4,2) .. 
  (7,0);  
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (8,3);
\draw 
  (1,0) 
    .. controls (3,2) and (5,2) .. 
  (7,0);  
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (8,3);
\draw[overlay] 
  (1,0) 
    .. controls (10,2) and (-2,2) .. 
  (7,0);  
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,-1) grid (8,1);
\draw 
  (1,0) 
    .. controls (3,2) and (5,-2) .. 
  (7,0);  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}`

Comment: The third one is particularly good to explain why I meant with "pull toward them" you start in `(1,0)` then the path is pull towards `(10,2)` and then it goes backwards when it is pulled towards `(-2,2)` and finally it heads to `(7,0)`. I immediately see the loop forming in my head :)

Comment: Make the same mental exercise for the other examples and you'll get an intuition on control points. Think of a control point as "pulling the path towards it". Sorry about these lonh chain of comments.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you. That's the first intelligible thing anybody has told me about them. Though actually most of the documentation concentrates on the syntax - it assumes you already know what they are. So a control point which is further away pulls it more? It isn't just the direction which matters? `(5.5,1)` is not equivalent to `(10,2)`?

Comment: Do you mean "direction" as from the origin? If so, then no, it's not just direction whcih matters. In  `\draw (1,0) 
    .. controls (4,2) .. 
  (7,0);`  and `\draw (1,0) 
    .. controls (8,4) .. 
  (7,0);`  
the control points have the same direction (are in the same line through the origin), but in the latter case the path will be biased towards the right and upwards, compaired to the former.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I meant direction relative to the curve - some point on the curve, presumably. So not the origin, because the curve starts at `(1,0)`. But `(10,2)` and `(5.5,1)` are in the same direction from that point (which might be the wrong point to think about - I'm not sure where gets pulled). But the results are different.

Comment: Then, if I understand you, yes, a point which is further away pulls the curve more or "stronger".

Comment: By the way, you can also use the `hobby` package to let the program choose adequate control points by itself. http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/hobby/hobby_doc.pdf

Comment: "Note that I know the two images look identical. That is because they are the same image. That's my point." -- What is your point? I don't understand!

Comment: @FranckPastor 404!

Comment: If you don't understand my point., you probably don't share my confusion and don't need the answer to this question ;). Since the question has received a very useful answer, I'm quite content. My point was not knowing how to go from curve to points, as opposed to going from points to curve. That was the question.

Comment: This is not really addressing your question, but might help people coming by. So note that  [Inkscape can export to tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151232/exporting-from-inkscape-to-latex-via-tikz), and for very basic projects [Tikzit](https://tikzit.github.io/) might be interesting.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The analogy that I've always used is to think of control points as points that "pull the path towards them". In the examples below, control points are drawn using the same color than the corresponding path in which they were used; when there are two control points, the number below the point indicates which one goes first in the code.

[image]

The example with the loop is particularly good to explain why I meant with "pull the curve towards them": the path starts in `(1,0)` then the path is pulled towards `(10,2)` and then it goes backwards when it is pulled towards `(-2,2)` and finally it heads towards `(7,0)`. Immediately you can see the loop forming in your head.

The code for the image:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,paperheight=40cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\DrawControl[3]{
  node[#2,circle,fill=#2,inner sep=2pt,label={above:$#1$},label={[black]below:{\footnotesize#3}}] at #1 {}
}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\centering

One control point:\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (8,5);
\draw[ultra thick] 
  (1,0) 
    .. controls (4,0) .. 
  (7,0) \DrawControl{(4,0)}{black}{};  
\draw[ultra thick,blue] 
  (1,0) 
    .. controls (4,2) .. 
  (7,0) \DrawControl{(4,2)}{blue}{};  
\draw[ultra thick,red] 
  (1,0) 
    .. controls (4,6) .. 
  (7,0) \DrawControl{(4,6)}{red}{};  
\end{tikzpicture}\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (8,5);
\draw[ultra thick] 
  (1,0) 
    .. controls (2,0) .. 
  (7,0) \DrawControl{(2,0)}{black}{};  
\draw[ultra thick,blue] 
  (1,0) 
    .. controls (2,2) .. 
  (7,0) \DrawControl{(2,2)}{blue}{};  
\draw[ultra thick,red] 
  (1,0) 
    .. controls (2,6) .. 
  (7,0) \DrawControl{(2,6)}{red}{};  
\end{tikzpicture}

\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}

Two control points:\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (8,3);
\draw[ultra thick,blue] 
  (1,0) 
    .. controls (3,2) and (5,2) .. 
  (7,0) \DrawControl{(3,2)}{blue}{1}\DrawControl{(5,2)}{blue}{2} ;  
\draw[ultra thick,red] 
  (1,0) 
    .. controls (3,4) and (5,4) .. 
  (7,0) \DrawControl{(3,4)}{red}{1}\DrawControl{(5,4)}{red}{2};  
\end{tikzpicture}\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (8,3);
\draw[ultra thick,blue] 
  (1,0) 
    .. controls (2,2) and (6,2) .. 
  (7,0) \DrawControl{(2,2)}{blue}{1}\DrawControl{(6,2)}{blue}{2};  
\draw[ultra thick,red] 
  (1,0) 
    .. controls (2,4) and (6,4) .. 
  (7,0) \DrawControl{(2,4)}{red}{1}\DrawControl{(6,4)}{red}{2};  
\end{tikzpicture}

\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}

\vspace{3cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (8,3);
\draw[overlay,ultra thick,blue] 
  (1,0) 
    .. controls (10,2) and (-2,2) .. 
  (7,0) \DrawControl{(10,2)}{blue}{1}\DrawControl{(-2,2)}{blue}{2};  
\draw[overlay,ultra thick,red] 
  (1,0) 
    .. controls (12,4) and (-4,4) .. 
  (7,0) \DrawControl{(12,4)}{red}{1}\DrawControl{(-4,4)}{red}{2};  
\end{tikzpicture}

\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\draw[help lines] (0,-2) grid (8,2);
\draw[ultra thick,blue] 
  (1,0) 
    .. controls (3,2) and (5,-2) .. 
  (7,0) \DrawControl{(3,2)}{blue}{1}\DrawControl{(5,-2)}{blue}{2};  
\draw[ultra thick,red] 
  (1,0) 
    .. controls (-1,5) and (8,-5) .. 
  (7,0) \DrawControl{(-1,5)}{red}{1}\DrawControl{(8,-5)}{red}{2};  
\end{tikzpicture}

\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}

\end{document}
```

With the examples and, hopefully with the help of the "pull towards" analogy, it should become clear that, in order to get a path like the one in your question, you should use two control points with these characteristics:

- Both control points should have same absolute value for the y-coordinate (given the symmetry with respect to the x-axis). The y-coordinate for the first control point should be positive (to pull the path upwards), whilst the y-coordinate for the second control point should be negative (to pull the path downwards).
- The  distance between the x-coordinates for the initial point and the first control point should be equal to the one between the x-coordinates for the second control point and the final point (given the symmetry with respect to the "middle" point on the path).

So

```
\draw (0,0) .. controls (??,??) and (??,??) .. (3,0);
```

will become something like

```
\draw (0,0) .. controls (1,2) and (2,-2) .. (3,0);
```

Answer (score 57):

Just for fun, here is an animation of some Bézier curves and of their control points.

[image]

To get this picture, compile the document below then call `convert` from `imagemagick`:

```
convert -density 150 tikz-bezier-animation.pdf tikz-bezier-animation.gif
```

The document (`tikz-bezier-animation.tex`):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,backgrounds}

\tikzset{
  show curve controls/.style={
    decoration={
      show path construction,
      curveto code={
        \draw[#1!50]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
        -- (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta)
        -- (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
        -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast)
        ;
        \fill[#1!50] (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) circle(1pt);
        \fill[#1!50] (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) circle(1pt);
        \draw[#1,line width=1pt]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
        .. controls (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta)
                and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) ..
        (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      }
    },decorate
  }
}

\begin{document}
\foreach \p in {0,10,...,360} {
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
      \path (-4,-2) rectangle (4,2.1);
      \coordinate (a) at (-2,0);
      \coordinate (b) at (2,0);
      \path (a) ++(1,0) ++(\p:0 and 2) coordinate (a1);
      \path (b) ++(-1,0) ++({180-\p}:0 and 2) coordinate (b1);
      \draw[show curve controls={red}] (a) .. controls (a1) and (b1) .. (b);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-4.5cm]
      \path (-4,-1) rectangle (4,4);
      \coordinate (a) at (-2,0);
      \coordinate (b) at (2,0);
      \path (a) ++(45:3) ++(\p:3 and 0) coordinate (a1);
      \path (b) ++(90+45:3) ++(180-\p:3 and 0) coordinate (b1);
      \draw[show curve controls={blue}] (a) .. controls (a1) and (b1) .. (b);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-6cm]
      \path (-4,-3) rectangle (4,4);
      \coordinate (a) at (-2,0);
      \coordinate (b) at (2,0);
      \path (a) ++(1,0) [rotate=45] ++(\p:0 and 2) coordinate (a1);
      \path (b) ++(-1,0) [rotate=45] ++({180+\p}:0 and 2) coordinate (b1);
      \draw[show curve controls={green!50!black}]
        (a) .. controls (a1) and (b1) .. (b);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      \fill[white] (current bounding box.south west)
         rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't actually view the animations for some reason, but I'm sure they are good!

Answer (score 41):

In addition to other answers, it is worth noting that it is possible to specify the control points relative to the ends points. When used in combination with polar coordinates, this approach gives a slightly more intuitive approach (I think) to visualising how a Bézier curve will turn out.

In particular, it makes it a bit easier to make consecutive Bézier curves appear to be smoothly joined: in most cases it is possible to just add 180 degrees to the angle of the second control point of the previous curve or (as pointed out by Paul Gaborit) use the same angle and reverse the sign of the distance:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{%
  show curve controls/.style={
    postaction={
      decoration={
        show path construction,
        curveto code={
          \draw [blue] 
            (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta)
            (\tikzinputsegmentlast) -- (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb);
          \fill [red, opacity=0.5] 
            (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) circle [radius=.5ex]
            (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) circle [radius=.5ex];
        }
      },
      decorate
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (-4, -1) grid (4, 5);
\draw [show curve controls]
  (-3, 4) .. controls ++(135:-1) and ++(135:1) .. (0, 4);
\draw [show curve controls] (0, 0) 
  .. controls ++(165:-1) and ++(240: 1) .. ( 3, 2)
  .. controls ++(240:-1) and ++(165:-1) .. ( 2, 4)
  .. controls ++(165: 1) and ++(175:-2) .. (-1, 2)
  .. controls ++(175: 2) and ++(165: 1) .. ( 0, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of `(60:1)` (in fact `(240-180:1)`), you may use `(240:-1)` to use exactly the same angle.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Even better! I've updated my answer.

Comment: This example is super helpful.  I've always fought painful battles with bezier curves, but using your example, I just drew one with multiple control points that I actually like.  Thanks!

Comment: This is one of those answers I wish I could upvote more than once.

Answer (score 19):

In addition to Gonzalo Medina's answer, I would like to point out that another criterion you could base your drawings on is that the Bézier curve is *tangent* to the lines going from the first control point to the second and from the second last to the last. This could be something that gives you an idea of the initial and final path of the curve (something like the `to [out=...,in=...]` notation).

In the following examples I borrowed some of GM's points for comparison purposes.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  ctrlpoint/.style={%
    draw=gray,
    circle,
    inner sep=0,
    minimum width=1ex,
  }
}
\newcommand\Bezier[4]{% \bezier (lowercase 'b') was already defined elsewhere
  \node (p1) [ctrlpoint,label=90:$P_1$] at (#1) {};
  \node (p2) [ctrlpoint,label=90:$P_2$] at (#2) {};
  \node (p3) [ctrlpoint,label=90:$P_3$] at (#3) {};
  \node (p4) [ctrlpoint,label=90:$P_4$] at (#4) {};
  \draw [gray] (p1) -- (p2) -- (p3) -- (p4);
  \draw [blue] (#1) .. controls (#2) and (#3) .. (#4);
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \Bezier{0,0}{1,1}{2,-1}{3,0}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
    \Bezier{0,0}{9,2}{-2,2}{7,0}
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[yshift=-5cm]
    \Bezier{0,0}{1,3}{2,3}{7,0}
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=8cm,yshift=-5cm]
    \Bezier{0,0}{-2,4}{4,-1}{5,0}
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to see a naive implementation of a 5 points-based Bézier curve, I posted a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222200/tikz-foreach-loop-not-executing-expected-number-of-iterations) a short while ago; it has a link to a Wikipedia page explaining the algorithm used and demonstrating the "tangency" aforementionend.

Comment: Thanks for this. This is helpful, too, although I don't find it quite so intuitive as the 'pulling' model. But it does help relate this to GIMP, which is definitely useful as I have some idea of how that works. (It helps link what I see in GIMP with the 'pulling' analogy in other answers.)

Answer (score 12):

I found picking control points to be such a terrible experience that I wrote [some code](https://github.com/stevecheckoway/tikzlibraryspline) to construct a Bézier spline through some given points.

You load the library in the usual way: `\usetikzlibrary{spline}`.

Some examples from the manual (the pictures are taken from the manual so the background color is different):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spline}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (3,2);
  \node[draw=red, circle] (A) at (1,0) {A};
  \node[draw=blue, rectangle] (B) at (2,2) {B};
  \node[draw=green!60!black, circle] (C) at (3,1) {C};
  \draw (A) to[spline through={(0,1)(B)(2,1)}] (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spline}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (3,2);
  \coordinate (A) at (1,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (2,2);
  \coordinate (C) at (3,1);

  \draw (A) to[spline coordinates=S,
               closed spline through={(0,1)(B)(2,1)(C)}] (A);
  \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using \i+1] in {1,2,...,\tikzsplinesegments} {
    \draw[semithick]  (S K-\i) -- (S P-\i)
                      (S K-\j) -- (S Q-\i);
    \path[fill=green!60!black] (S P-\i) circle (2pt);
    \path[fill=red] (S Q-\i) circle (2pt);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So my answer is: I don't! I'd much rather let the computer pick the control points.

Comment: Thanks. You don't use `hobby`? Could you make your examples complete? Or show how you're loading the code, at least? To be honest, I try hard to stick to stuff on CTAN (except for my own code), because keeping track is just a nightmare otherwise. Are you planning to upload this? I think `hobby` is more intuitive, but, of course, it has a manual and so on.

Comment: I actually didn't know about hobby. Probably would have saved me the effort of implementing this. I haven't decided what to do with my code yet, to be honest, but I _did_ make a manual https://github.com/stevecheckoway/tikzlibraryspline/releases/download/v1.0.0/tikzlibraryspline.pdf

Comment: Sorry, @cfr, I forgot to @ you. I've been gone from this site so long, I've kinda forgotten how it works.

Comment: @cfr, come to think of it, I think it's good I didn't know about hobby. It doesn't seem to play nice with nodes as coordinates or nodes placed along the path. Maybe I'll add a comparison section to my manual.

Comment: You don't actually need the @, I don't think, if only one person has commented (other than you). At least, I don't *think* so, though I might be misremembering the rules. You can always specify a node's anchor to get a coordinate, of course, but Hobby does want coordinates, I think, as you say. I would expect it to work with a node on the path, though - slightly surprised it doesn't.

Comment: One of my goals, which may certainly not be anyone else's, was that the path through a node would exit the border at exactly the same place as if the curve were to the center of the node. That part is pretty slow though due to the use of the fantastic `intersections` library.

Comment: @TH: could you tell me how to typeset the above code? I guess I have to copy some file to my TeXlive (on Windows 10) , right? By the way, i am waiting for comparison with hobby library in your manual.

Comment: @BlackMild I'm not sure I follow your question. You want to typeset the code as in have the code itself appear in your output PDF? In that case, use the `listings` package. If you're asking how to use the library, I think you just need to download https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stevecheckoway/tikzlibraryspline/master/tikzlibraryspline.code.tex and put it in the same directory as your main `.tex` file. I definitely dropped the ball on updating the manual with a comparison though.

Answer (score 2):

Chỉ cho vui thôi. (Just for fun)

Compile with [Asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/).

```
import graph;
pair Bezier(pair P[], real t)
{
pair Bezi;
for (int k=0; k <= P.length-1; ++k)
{  Bezi=Bezi+choose(P.length-1,k)*(1-t)^(P.length-1-k)*t^k*P[k]; }
return Bezi;
}
pair BezierRecursion(pair P[], real t){
int n = P.length - 1;
pair Q[][]=new pair[P.length][P.length];
for (int i=0; i <= n; ++i){ Q[i][0]=P[i]; }
for (int j=1; j <=n; ++j){
for (int i=j; i<=n; ++i){
Q[i][j]=(1-t)*Q[i-1][j-1]+t*Q[i][j-1];
}
}
return Q[n][n];
}
unitsize(1cm);
pair[] P={(0,0),(4,1),(5,3),(2,5),(3.8,6.5)}; // 5 points
pair F(real t){return Bezier(P,t);}
pair G(real t){return BezierRecursion(P,t);}
write(F(0.76)); write(G(0.76));
draw(graph(F,0,1),red);
dot(P); 
draw(operator --(... P));
draw(shift(4,0)*graph(G,0,1),red);
dot(shift(4,0)*P);  draw(shift(4,0)*operator --(... P));
```

[image]

An animation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#/media/File:B%C3%A9zier_4_big.gif

```
import animate;
settings.tex="pdflatex"; 
settings.outformat="pdf"; 

animation Ani;
import graph;
size(400);

pair Bezier(pair P[], real t)
{
pair Bezi;
// real choose(int n, int k); // Mathematical functions (page 69)
for (int k=0; k <= P.length-1; ++k)
{
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve
Bezi=Bezi+choose(P.length-1,k)*(1-t)^(P.length-1-k)*t^k*P[k];
}
return Bezi;
}
pair[] P={(0,0),(-.5,3),(4,3),(6,0),(9,2.6)};
pair F(real t){return Bezier(P,t);}
real t=0.5;
pair A[]=new pair[4], B[]=new pair[3], C[]=new pair[2], D;
for (int k=0; k <= 50; ++k)
{
t=k/50;
save();
// A array has 4 points
for (int i : sequence(A.length)) { A[i] = interp(P[i],P[i+1],t); }
// B array has 3 points
for (int i : sequence(B.length)) { B[i] = interp(A[i],A[i+1],t); }
// C array has 2 points
C[0]=interp(B[0],B[1],t);
C[1]=interp(B[1],B[2],t); 
// D array has 1 points
D=interp(C[0],C[1],t);

draw(operator --(... P),magenta+0.7bp);
draw(operator --(... A),(t != 0) ? green+0.7bp : invisible);
draw(operator --(... B),(t != 0) ? orange+0.7bp : invisible);
draw(operator --(... C),(t != 0) ? blue+0.7bp : invisible);
draw(graph(F,0,t),(t != 0) ? red+1.3bp : invisible);
dot(P,magenta);
dot(A,(t != 0) ? green : invisible);
dot(B,(t != 0) ? orange : invisible);
dot(C,(t != 0) ? blue : invisible);
dot(D,pink);
label(Label(format("t=%.2f",t),Fill(white)),(3,0));
Ani.add();
restore();
}
erase();
Ani.movie(BBox(3mm,Fill(black)));
```

[image]

Comment: Your codes and examples are beautiful. But these are Bézier curves of order 4 whereas basically, TikZ (and PDF) uses cubic Bézier curves.

Comment: @PaulGaborit I believe that that code above can draw `all` Bézier curves. :-) An array has `4` points, I will have a cubic Bézier curve.