# intersection between line and curve

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to use  `\usetikzlibrary{intersections}`

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
    \usetikzlibrary{intersections,shapes}
    \usepackage{esvect}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
%\draw [color=gray,help lines, step=.5] (-1.3,-1.3) grid (5.3,5.3);

\draw[-stealth ] (-1.3,0) -- (5.3,0) node[below] {\footnotesize $x$};
\draw[-stealth ](0,-1.3) -- (0,5.3) node[left] {\footnotesize $y$};
\draw (0pt,-10pt) node[left] {\footnotesize $0$};
\draw[ dashed] (0,1.9 )node[ left]{\footnotesize $f(b)$} -| (1.144,0)
node[below]{\footnotesize $b$} ;
\draw[ dashed] (0,3.1928)node[ left]{\footnotesize $f(a)$} -| (3.2 ,0)
node[ below]{\footnotesize $a$} ;
\pgfsetstrokecolor{rgb,1:red,1;green,0;blue,0}
\pgfsetlinewidth{1pt} 
\pgfsetroundjoin \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfxy(0.582,0.7937)}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfxy(0.863,1.4009)}{\pgfxy(1.144,2.0082)}{\pgfxy(1.5608,2.328)}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfxy(1.9777,2.6479)}{\pgfxy(2.5303,2.6802)}{\pgfxy(2.9365,2.9365)}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfxy(3.3427,3.1928)}{\pgfxy(3.6026,3.6731)}{\pgfxy(3.8624,4.1534)}
\pgfstroke
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please forgive if I have missed your question... but what is your question?

Comment: how do use commande `intersections`

Comment: @khaledhariz, your image is drawn with pure pgfs. As far as know, library `intersection` work with TikZ macros. Draw your curve and lines which intersect it with `draw` macro, give the names to curve and line and then look for intersection.

Comment: So we can not use `intersection`, except in the case of function name . the curve   drawing using **texgraph**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Khaled you can name your paths with `name path=patha`, `name path=pathb`. then to find coordinate for intersection of `patha` and `pathb` with `name intersections={of=patha and pathb}`. where intersections are named `intersection-1`, `intersection-2`,... and so on.

**Code**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\draw[->](-1.3,0) -- (5.3,0) node[below] {\footnotesize $x$};
\draw[->](0,-1.3) -- (0,5.3) node[left] {\footnotesize $y$};
\node[below left]at(0,0) {\footnotesize $0$};
\draw[red,line width=1pt,name path=plot](0.5,0.5)..controls(1,3)and(3,2)..(4,4.5);
\node[below](a)at(1.2,0){$a$};
\node[below](b)at(3,0){$b$};
\path[name path=froma](a)--+(0,4);
\path[name path=fromb](b)--+(0,4);
\draw[dashed,name intersections={of=froma and plot}](a)--(intersection-1)--(0,0|-intersection-1)node[left]{f(a)};
\draw[dashed,name intersections={of=fromb and plot}](b)--(intersection-1)--(0,0|-intersection-1)node[left]{f(b)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exact ...Thank you very much my binom  , I'll never forget me help you

Comment: salim how to give coordinate exact if you use  controls point

Comment: You can take a look at this answer [how-does-one-pick-control-points-to-control-bézier-curves-in-tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255234/how-does-one-pick-control-points-to-control-b%C3%A9zier-curves-in-tikz).