# The coordinates of control points

Tags: tikz-pgf

My problem is, that when I want to draw a curve I don't know where to put the control points. Is there a method for calculating the coordinates? For example I want to draw this curve here and I don't know where are the controls. I can make a guess but that's not exact.

[image: The curve]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can use Hobby's algorithm (or the [hobby package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hobby?lang=en), which implements it) to specify only the tangent directions and let the computer come up with reasonable control points.

Comment: The OP is asking HOW to calculate the control points of a Beizer. Which is more of a maths question, like this:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1037222/calculating-control-points-of-cubic-b%C3%A9zier-curve

Comment: @William'Ike'Eisenhauer, where did the OP mention **Beizer**?

Comment: Sorry if I did not mention, but yes I need the method of the calculations. Since you are all LaTeX users I thought you can write me the method. By the way @CroCo, your solution was quite good, I liked it.

Comment: The thing is, I don't know how many of us *calculate* the control points. Probably some of the specialists do, but I'm betting that I'm not the only one who does not. I asked [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255234/how-does-one-pick-control-points-to-control-b%C3%A9zier-curves-in-tikz) about how to figure out values for control points. But note that I was explicitly *not* asking how to calculate precise values but, rather, how to think about them intuitively. Probably the information there is of little interest, but may explain why asking elsewhere may be more fruitful!

Comment: @CroCo, OP didn't say it explicitly Beizer, but other options i.e. NURBS, B Splines, and Hermites are all going to be a lot more complex for a simple curve like this than just simply defining intuitive Cubic Beizer control points. But I will grant you they didn't specifically say Beizer, but they did mention calculating them, which is much easier to do if you think of it as a Cubic Beizer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this is a curve. You can choose three points and connect them.

`(A) to [out=angle1,in=angle2] (B);`

where A and B are points and angle1 and angle2 control the way curved line enters and leaves a point.

[image]

This is the code

```
\documentclass[border={10}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A)  at (0,0);
\coordinate (B)  at (0,-1);
\coordinate (C)  at (1,0);

\draw[very thick] (A) to [out=225,in=180,looseness=1.5] (B);
\draw[very thick] (B) to [out=0,in=270]               (C);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Edit:
Regarding the `in` and `out`, I will show you the way the curved line leaves A point and the rest will be clear. Regarding `looseness`, it curves the line more. Try to change it to see its effect.

[image]

**Optional:** 
This is the code for the above picture

```
\documentclass[border={10}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        Circ/.style={circle,fill=blue,thick,
                      inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1mm}
]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\coordinate (A)  at (0,0);
\coordinate (B)  at (0,-1);
\coordinate (C)  at (1,0);

\draw[very thick] (A) to [out=225,in=180,looseness=1.5] (B);
\draw[very thick] (B) to [out=0,in=270]                 (C);


\draw[red] (-.8,0) -- (1.5,0);
\draw[red] ( 0,.5) -- (0,-1.3);

\node [Circ,label={[xshift=-5mm]30:A}]             at (A) {};
\node [Circ,label={[xshift=-5mm,yshift=-5mm]30:B}] at (B) {};
\node [Circ,label={[xshift=-5mm]30:C}]             at (C) {};

\draw [green] (.1,0) arc (0:225:.1) node[xshift=-2.5mm,yshift=.15mm] {\tiny out} ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks that's useful, but I have a question: how did you calculate the "in" and "out" angles and what does "looseness" do?

Comment: @ostal123, please see the update. Also,  I've changed `looseness` to `1.5` to make it more smooth and curved.

Comment: @ostal123, regarding the actual angles, since you didn't specify any thing about the curve, I've just tried to mimic your picture.

Comment: Alright, I understand now. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @ostal123, you are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `..controls (coordinate) and (coordinate) ..` syntax to draw Bezier curves.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (.35,.75);
  \coordinate (B) at (.85,.75);
  \coordinate (C1) at (-.4,.1);
  \coordinate (C2) at (.86,.12);
  \draw[red] (A) .. controls (C1) and (C2) .. (B);
  \node[red,draw,fill,inner sep=1pt] at (A) {};
  \node[red,draw,fill,inner sep=1pt] at (B) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I put your image in the background to emphasize the analogy.

> [image]

Comment: Please, let me know how did you calculate the coordinates of controls.

Comment: I think it will be helpful to show the code for loading the picture and drawing on it. Just suggestion so that the OP can modify the parameters accordingly .

Comment: @ostal123 I determined the control point by mere trial and error, i.e. I varied them until it fit.

Comment: @CroCo You can find the instructions on how to draw on an image with TikZ in this [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz).