# Tikz: close path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-path

I need to draw a closed shape using controls and then round the heads.
The problem is the starting point (The upper one) is not rounded as if the shape is not closed, and the `cycle` command is not working correctly.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[margin=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw[rounded corners = 50pt, fill=red] (0,5) .. controls(0.2,1) .. (10,0) ..controls (0.2,-1) ..(0,-5).. controls(-0.2,-1)..(-10,0)..controls(-0.2,1)..(0,5);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
I want to know why this is happening?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Why don't you just add another `.. controls() .. (0, 5)` that leads you back to your end point?

Comment: @Timm I tried this and the output is weird

Comment: I saw the problem, and tried playing with it, but could not really find a solution.. however, have a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33610/100384) and [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255258/100384), it might help you with your control points. However, I don't really understand this right now, when I apply the style defined there your example does not work like theirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a real solution, but the following workaround may be acceptable. I used `line width = 4pt, line join = round, red` and `cycle` for the last point to give the effect of `rounded corners = 50pt`.

```
\documentclass[margin=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=4pt, line join=round, red]
\draw [fill=red] (0,5) .. controls(0.2,1) .. (10,0) ..controls (0.2,-1) ..(0,-5).. controls(-0.2,-1)..(-10,0) .. controls(-0.2,1).. cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do not think that is a 50pt rounded corner. This is what 50pt should be https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVBs9.png.

Comment: @Symbol1: Yes, that large 50pt is the real source of the problem, so I tried to preserve the shape the OP wanted using thick lines.

Comment: @Symbol1 Almost what I wanted! Good idea